# ZipArchive missing whitespaces?

Tags: c#, system.io.compression

i don't know how to explain my issue, but i'm gonna try.
i have a batch services that creates several text files and put them in a zip file.

there are two files that have a lot of white spaces. we are talking about thousand of white spaces between text.

the thing is this file that i've sent by email, when it is uncompressed it has less characters that it has to be. it should 10170 columns, but instead i have 10152.

this is the way that i've create the zip based on the stringbuilders.

```
 var mStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var zip = new ZipArchive(mStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            foreach (var builder in Builders)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(builder.Value.ToString()))
                    continue;
                var entry = zip.CreateEntry(builder.Key);
                var stream = entry.Open();
                var value = builder.Value.ToString().TrimEnd(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
                var values = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(value);
                stream.Write(values, 0, values.Length);
                stream.Close();
            }

        }
```

Then the stream is attached as a mail attachment.

thanks!

Comment: you're doing a `TrimEnd`, so it looks like its just doing what it is expected to do?

Comment: Have you verified that `value` contains what you expect?  That `TrimEnd()` sure looks suspect.

Comment: and look into the encoding: reducing from Unicode to 1252 *might* have this effect (thinking about stuff like the no-break-space and other fancy whitespace)

Comment: No, the trimend is working as expected.

Comment: dlatikay yes that could be, I will try with other encoding.